# Why does my code result in "cannot instantiate abstract class"?

Tags: c++, observer-pattern

This is the line where the error occurs:

```
this->_tbfCmdHandler.reset(new Bar());
```

> facade_impl.cpp(202): error C2259:
>   'FOO::Bar' : cannot
>   instantiate abstract class
>   due to following members:
>   'void Subscriber::update(T)' : is
>   abstract          with
>              T=char &
>
> observer.h(66)
>   : see declaration of
>   'Subscriber::update'
>   with
>   T=char & 
>   'void Subscriber::update(T)' : is
>   abstract           with
>             T=const char &
>
> observer.h(66)
>   : see declaration of
>   'Subscriber::update'
>   with
>   T=const char &           ]

This is the declaration for Facade::Implementation

```
namespace FOO
{
class Facade::Implementation 
                :public Subscriber<const char& >                     
{
```

facade.cpp

```
FOO::Facade::Facade () : impl (new Implementation)
{

    Singleton<SPM::Facade>::instance ();
}


The update functions:
    void update( const char *aMsg)   
    {
        printf("foo");
    };
```

I hope this helps to figure out where I can find the error.

Comment: 3 down votes is a bit harsh for the new guy... Just one would have been sufficient.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are inheriting from an abstract class, so you need to implement the void update( const char& ) function inside class Facade::Implementation.

You did define an update function, but it is not related in any way to Subscriber. You have to put it inside your implementation.

Comment: This matches it mostly. "You did define an update function, but it is not related in any way to Subscriber" Subsciber wanted a &reVal but there was a "hidden" implemenation with a *ptrVal

Answer (score 3):

You have already written your answer. The class is abstract, which means it has pure virtual methods. So, you first have to implement these methods.

Comment: i thought i've implemented the method with this line:

void update( const RecoveryState &dummy){};

Comment: Christofer, the error message indicates that the compiler expects you to implement a method `void update(char&)`. Make sure to always read the *entire* error message before concluding that your code is right.

Comment: Well, the compiler obviously thinks you haven't. Now for us to tell, you will have to show some code.

Answer (score 2):

Read up about [polymorphism](http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/polymorphism/) and what an abstract class is.

Abstract means that it is not completely defined yet and therefore, you cannot instanciate that because you don't have all the parts figured out.

It's like trying to start a car without the enginge.

Answer (score 2):

Try reading this C++ [FAQ](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/abcs.html#faq-22.3)

Comment: Linking to outside material is a fine way to start, but you should at least report on what the external material says.

Answer (score 1):

This is what the problem solves:

I removed the void update( const char &aMsg), and saw that there was another one
"void update( char *aMsg)"

Why this function wasn't reported by the compiler is a miracle...
removing the non-const and the Pointer(instead of Reference)-function fixes the problem finally.

Answer (score 0):

The error says `void Subscriber<T>::update(T)' : is abstract` with `T=char &`, so you need to define `void update(char&)`, not just `void update( const RecoveryState &dummy){}`.

Comment: there is also a function for char:
 void update( char &aMsg)  
 {
  printf("\n>>>>>debug msg \n");
 }